# python xpath IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, list, exception, if-statement, try-except

I am grabbing a value from url source page by xpath. but this is not existed. so I want to **pass** the requests and try to grab that value again: what I tried:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
url='http://www.example.com'
cont=requests.get(url)
tree=html.fromstring(cont)
out=tree.xpath('...')[0]
```

When I run it I have the following Error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I request for grabbing value again in this case?

## update

I know this error means xpath doesn't exist. so I want to request to that url to grab xpath again.

Comment: Probably the xpath doesn't exist.

Comment: I know..Yes xpath doesn't exist.. so I want to request to url again if it is not existed

Comment: @MortezaLSC Try Except??

Comment: @Vincent Beltman Thank you... could you possibly answer more detailed by changing the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Try Except

```
import requests
from lxml import html

def do_get(xpath): # OR URL What ever you need
    url='http://www.example.com'
    cont=requests.get(url)
    tree=html.fromstring(cont)
    out=tree.xpath(xpath)[0]

try:
    do_get('....')
except:
    do_get('....')
```

Or if you wanna do it forever until you get the right one:

```
def do_get(xpath):
    url='http://www.example.com'
    cont=requests.get(url)
    tree=html.fromstring(cont)
    out=tree.xpath(xpath)[0]

while True:
    try:
        do_get('....')
        break
    except:
        pass
```